# Angular interceptor handling [object,object]

Tags: angular, interceptor

Hi I'm trying to display nicely the errors for login/register etc through a toastr notification from my error interceptor.

The issue is sometimes I cant catch all the errors as I need.

Here is my interceptor

```
    export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error) {
          switch (error.status) {
            case 400:
              debugger;
              if (error.error.errors) {
                const modalStateErrors = [];
                for (const key in error.error.errors) {
                  if (error.error.errors[key]) {
                    modalStateErrors.push(error.error.errors[key]);
                  }
                }
                throw modalStateErrors.flat();
              } else {
                error.statusText = error.error;
                this.toastr.error(error.statusText, error.status);
              }
              break;
            case 401:
              error.statusText = 'Unauthorized';
              this.toastr.error(error.statusText, error.status);
              break;
            case 404:
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/not-found');
              break;
            case 500:
              const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
                state: { error: error.error },
              };
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/server-error', navigationExtras);
              break;
            default:
              this.toastr.error('Something unexpected went wrong');
              console.log(error);
              break;
          }
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is located here:

```
if (error.error.errors) {
    const modalStateErrors = [];
    for (const key in error.error.errors) {
        if (error.error.errors[key]) {
modalStateErrors.push(error.error.errors[key]);
              }
            }
            throw modalStateErrors.flat();
          }
```

This type of error it works well.
[image]

But here comes the issue when there are mulptiple errors
[image]

or like that
[image]

I tried many approches but noting is seems to work. Those any can take a look? How can i catch all those types of errors and display them correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to do something like:

```js
if(Array.isArray(error.error) {
   error.error.forEach( item => {
     modalStateErrors.push(item); // or whatever value you need from item
   })
}
else {
   modalStateErrors.push(error.error);
}
```